# Validate a mongodb query syntax programmatically

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have an API method where the user can pass in their own query. The field in the collection is simply ns, so the user might pass something like:

```
v.search = function(query: Object){

   // query => {ns:{$in:['foo','bar',baz]}}  // valid!

   // query => {ns:{$in:{}}}  // invalid!

   // query => {ns:/foo/}     // valid!

});
```

is there some way to do this, like a smoke test that can fail queries that are obviously wrong?

**I am hoping that some MongoDB libraries would export this functionality... but in all likelihood they validate the query only by sending it to the database, which is in fact, the real arbiter of which query is valid/invalid.**

But I am looking to validate the query before sending it to the DB.

Comment: Why not run it on a blank collection and see if there was any parsing error?

Comment: @TarunLalwani yeah that's an expensive way to validate the query, takes too much time for a high-performance server.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some modules that are part of [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass) have been made open source.
There are two modules that may be of use for your use case:

- [mongodb-language-model](https://github.com/mongodb-js/mongodb-language-model)
- [mongodb-query-parser](https://github.com/mongodb-js/query-parser)

Although they may not fit your use case 100%, it should give you a very close validation. For example `npm install mongodb-language-model`, then:

```
var accepts = require('mongodb-language-model').accepts;

console.log(accepts('{"ns":{"$in":["foo", "bar", "baz"]}}'));  // true
console.log(accepts('{"ns":{"$in":{}}}'));                     // false
console.log(accepts('{"ns":{"$regex": "foo"}}'));              // true
```

Also may be of interest, `npm install mongodb-query-parser` to parse a string value into a JSON query. For example:

```
var parse = require('mongodb-query-parser');
var query = '{"ns":{"$in":["foo", "bar", "baz"]}}';
console.log(parse.parseFilter(query));    // {ns:{'$in':['foo','bar','baz']}}
```

Comment: nice, can you show an example of using `mongodb-query-parser` for our lovely audience?

Comment: Thank you @Wan Bachtiar. I was trying to find a query validator for sanitization for mongodb language when I stumbled on this. This library can help with basic sanity checks through validations against MongoDB Injections against a input from an api in nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to do otherwise than by reflecting query.ns object and checking every of its property / associated value